# Camera Frame and Object Frame

Tags: graphics, camera

I'm reading about Interactive Graphics, in particular I started the section about the viewing and I did not understand well this sentence:

> Initially, we start with the model-view matrix set to an identity matrix, so the camera frame and the object frame are identical.

I know what is a model view matrix and I know that in this case the camera view is oriented in the z negative axis. But I did not understand exactly what is the difference between the **object frame** and the **camera frame**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got 2 matrices: `View` and `Model` where `View` represents where from are you looking and in which directions (camera) and `Model` represents where is and how oriented your object you are currently rendering is.

However To speed-up rendering we are using just one cumulative matrix so:

```
ModelView = Inverse(View) * Model
```

so for example when you write something like this in **OpenGL**:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Then both `View` and `Model` matrices are identical and equal to unit matrix. After this point you add your incremental rotations and translations either to `View` (inverse order and direction) or to `Model` (normal order and direction).

For more info see:

- [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

Especially the last 3 links in there...